# returning 404 page error on form submission

Tags: 404-error

I have decided not to use a plugin to create a simple contact form on my site and used some php code to do the same job. This was so i could style the form exactly how I wanted to. However when I test the form and submit it, the user is sent to the 404 error page despite the url at the top of the browser indicating the contact page that exists. I'm not sure why that would be the case.?

I followed this tutorial to create the template page on my site
http://wpmu.org/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/

Here is the form on my test site
http://sandpit.jonathanbeech.co.uk/contact-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change input name for name field to contactName or cName etc.

```
<input type="text" name="cName" id="name" placeholder="Your name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput" value=""/>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, that worked. I assume that the input name that I chose was conflicting with some code in WordPress?